# PostgreSQL SELECT JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with making a proper SELECT for my exercise:

There are two tables that I have created: 
1. Customer
2. Order

ad. 1

```
CREATE TABLE public."Customer"
(
 id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Customer_id_seq"'::regclass),
  name text NOT NULL,
  surname text NOT NULL,
  address text NOT NULL,
  email text NOT NULL,
  password text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "Customer_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "Customer_email_key" UNIQUE (email)
)
```

ad.2

```
CREATE TABLE public."Order"
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Order_id_seq"'::regclass),
  customer_id integer NOT NULL,
  item_list text,
  order_date date,
  execution_date date,
  done boolean DEFAULT false,
  confirm boolean DEFAULT false,
  paid boolean DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT "Order_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "Order_customer_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
      REFERENCES public."Customer" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Please do not mind how columns properties were set.

The problem I have is following:

> How to make a SELECT query which will give me as a result ids and emails of customers who have ordered something after '2017-09-15'

I suppose that this should go with JOIN but none of the queries I tried have worked :/.

Thanks!

Comment: why are you escaping \" all the double quotes?

Comment: Can you show an example of queries you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post the queries that you tried, but in the meantime try this. It's a simple join :

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
    , email
FROM public."Customer" c
JOIN public."Order" o 
    ON c.id = o.customer_id
WHERE order_date > '2017-09-15'
```

Comment: This one worked just great, thank you. By the way - can you explain me why joining customer id to order date is wrong? Can I only make joins with columns that are linked with each other with foreign key?

Comment: Exactly. That's the relationship. There is no relationship between date and customer id. I recommend reading on foreign keys and joins.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: PK/FK is typically what you join on or you may get back unexpected results.  Logically however, the ID of customer (123) isn't ever likely to match Order.Order_date string ('2017-09-15')  Joined criteria should be on data of the same type; preferably of a PK/FK relationship; but not always necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In table "Order" you just need to add current constraint for customer id:

```
customer_id integer REFERENCES Customer (id)
```

for more information check this page:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-constraints.html

So, the query should be like this:

```
SELECT id, email
FROM Customer 
INNER JOIN Order 
    ON (Order.customer_id = Customer.id)
WHERE order_date >= '2017-09-15'
```

Also, the useful docs you can check: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html